# Test whether we can infer that the population means differ

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

[image]

Naturally, this is very insignificant and we fail to reject the null hypothesis. Is this the right calculation?

Comment: Seems this calls for a Welch 'separate variances' 2-sample t test. But with the simplification that the 'approximated DF' is given as $120 < 81 + 50 -2,$ so you don't need to deal with the messy formula for approx DF. Seems you have the right formula; maybe verify computations. I will check back later today or early tomorrow to see where it stands, and maybe help with interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

You mistakenly took ${\left(s_1^2\right)}^2$ and ${\left(s_2^2\right)}^2$ which gave you a much larger unpooled standard deviation than what it actually is.

For unequal variances, we should use Welch's Test.

Let $$H_0 : \mu_1 = \mu_2$$

$$H_a : \mu_1 \neq \mu_2$$

We have

$$\frac{\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2}}{\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}}}\sim t_v$$

where

$$\begin{align*}
v=\frac{\left(\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}\right)^2}{\frac{1}{n_1-1}\left(\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}\right)^2+\frac{1}{n_2-1}\left(\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}\right)^2}
&=\frac{\left(\frac{729}{81}+\frac{350}{50}\right)^2}{\frac{1}{81-1}\left(\frac{729}{81}\right)^2+\frac{1}{50-1}\left(\frac{350}{50}\right)^2}\\
&= 127
\end{align*}$$

Thus,

$$\frac{29-23}{\sqrt{\frac{729}{81}+\frac{350}{50}}}=1.5\sim t_{127}$$

But $t_{127,.025}\approx 1.97$

so we fail to reject the null hypothesis that the means differ.

Note that the p-value associated with $t_{127,.025}\approx 1.97$ is $0.136$ so we are closer to rejection than your calculations.

If we use the given value of $df=120$ we should come to a similar conclusion:

$$\frac{29-23}{\sqrt{\frac{729}{81}+\frac{350}{50}}}=1.5\sim t_{120}$$

and $t_{120,.025}\approx 1.9799$ so we fail to reject in this case as well.

Comment: Hmm, so this uses the more exact d.f. of 127, rather than the 120 given?

Comment: Yes, this would be the exact value. I didn't notice that the problem gave you a $df$ value to use!

Comment: My guess is that the problem says to use 120 instead of 127 because there is a row in the t table for 120 but not for 127. This seems correct, and the bit about incorrectly squaring variances is a nice catch. (+1) Just for a double-check, I will put the summary statistics into Minitab software to see what answers it gives.

Comment: Since your brought up Minitab, I was wondering what statistical program would you suggest a statistics student to focus on, to prepare for a career as a data analyst/statistician? I have been learning R and SAS, but primarily R.

Comment: I think "R and SAS, but primarily R" is just about right. Maybe eventually some Python. // I used MTB mainly because it is one of the few software programs that will accept summarized data (as here) and because its output requires little commentary. (Also I wrote a book about 18 years ago that used Minitab, so I'm very familiar with it.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I know some Python, but haven't used it for anything statistics-related.

Answer (score 2):

The sample means $\bar X_1 = 29$ and $\bar X_2 = 23$ differ. The
question is whether this difference in *sample* means is good
evidence of a difference in *population* means.

Because of sampling error, sample mean may not be entirely reliable
estimates of population means. The degree of reliability depends
on population variability and sample size.

It is appropriate to use the Welch two-sample t test unless one has
background information (before seeing the current data) that population
variances may differ. If population variances are not the same, the
traditional pooled t statistic may not have a t distribution. The
discrepancy may be especially severe if (as here) sample sizes differ and the
the smaller sample comes from what may be the population with the
larger variance.

The formula in @Remy's answer is correct. In order to check computations
I put the summary statistics (sample sizes, means, and SDs) into Minitab
software, with the results shown below:

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample   N  Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       81  29.0   27.0      3.0
2       50  23.0   18.7      2.6

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  6.00
95% CI for difference:  (-1.91, 13.91)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
   T-Value = 1.50  P-Value = 0.136  DF = 127
```

The P-value of the test is 0.136, which is considerable greater than 5%,
so we do not have evidence to reject $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$ against its
two-sided alternative.

The critical value for a two-sided test at the 5% level for DF = 127
is 1.9788. Because $|T| = 1.50 < 1.9788,$ we cannot reject at the 5% level.
[For DF 120, suggested in the problem, the critical value is 1.9799, which
leads to the same conclusion.]

Another indication that there is no significant difference between
population means is that the 95% CI for $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ (in the Minitab printout) contains $0.$
Thus 'no difference in population means' is a reasonable conclusion.

Finally, as a *rough* rule of thumb for a two-sample t test with both sample sizes
above 15, one can say that sample means must differ by more than about three
standard errors in order for the difference to be significant. Here, the
standard errors are $S_1/\sqrt{81} \approx 3$ and $S_2/\sqrt{50} \approx 2.6,$
whereas the absolute difference between sample means is only $|29 - 23| = 6.$ So it
is not a surprise that the precise computation of the Welch test does
not lead to rejection of $H_0.$

Comment: No, it's a typo. I'm still proofreading.. Fixed it. // Hope that's all the typos now. Suggest you click to Accept @Remy's careful computation and explanation of your error with the variances.